# How to generate onesignal notification message with in the phonegap app using ajax

Tags: ajax, cordova, onesignal

I am new to [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/cordova-sdk) notification.
I have to send the notification message through my phonegap app. I know the process how to send a new message process to send notification through onesignal dashboard.

Can anyone help me how to do it from the app using ajax call.
Thankyou.

Comment: Split the paragraph into 2. Added a link that, hopefully, makes the Q easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the notification from app by using the ajax call to **https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications** as following.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
   headers: {
        'Authorization':'Basic ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
  type: "POST",
  data: {"app_id" : "Your APP ID","contents":{"en":"message"},"included_segments":["All"],"data":{"abc": "123", "foo": "bar"}},
  dataType: "application/json"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  console.log("success");
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried the above code i got request failed:error @Naresh Kumar

Comment: POST https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications 400 ():jquery.js:4   
Request failed: error @Naresh Kumar

Comment: remove dataType parameter and do

Comment: and check the object which is in the data parameter is a valid ?

Comment: Tried removing datatype parameter got the same error @Naresh Kumar

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonBody = {
                  "app_id": "Onesignal App Id",
                  "include_player_ids": ["App Playerid"],
                  "headings": {
                                "en": "Sump"
                              },
                  "contents": {
                                "en": " Sump Level is 'Sumpper' "
                              }
              };
                var request = $.ajax({
                      url: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
                      headers: {
                            'Authorization':'Basic REST API Key',
                            'Content-Type':'application/json',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'SDK-Version',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                        },
                      type: "POST",
                      data: JSON.stringify(jsonBody),
                      dataType: "json"
                });
                console.log(request);

                    request.success(function(msg) {
                      console.log("success");
                    });

                    request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                      console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );

                    });
```